# What is an alternative to "sudo dpkg --configure -a" which removes the problematic package?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg

On a general basis I want to know which command I can use if I need to run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` to solve a problem with a package but if I don't want to continue the installation but abort it and remove the package.

---

Specifically, I tried to install `Citadel` on my Raspberry which I aborted during the download of a file. The process was not continuing and I did not find another way as to exit the ssh-session and later kill the process.

Now, I want to remove the package, but upon `apt remove citadel-suite` I get the error that I have to run `dpkg --configure -a`. If I run this it tries to install the package again and I run into the same problem.

Which command would instead purge all of the installed packages and give dpkg free?

Answer (score 0):

I now was able to `apt purge` the packages which I tried to install instead of running the above command. This resolved the issue. This was not possible before but probably it was due to a running process. So, there is no need to run `dpkg --configure -a`, just if you really want to finalize the installation.